# ruby/chef: what is the purpose of the 'node' stanza?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, test-kitchen

Here is a example snipit of code:

```
mwh_dir = "#{node['fmw']['middleware_home_dir']}"
```

I have just been using this syntax without being able to find details online of why I need to use the `node` stanza.

If someone could explain what the purpose of `node` is within that code.

note: `fmw` is an object defined in the .kitchen.yml and `middleware_home_dir` is a variable defined within that object.

Comment: "If someone could explain what the purpose of node is within that code." well conspicuously enough that is referencing a [`Node`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Node).  `Node#[]` delegates to [`Node::Attribute#[]`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Node/Attribute) which is a subclass of [`Mash`](Chef's subclass of a native ruby `Hash`). So in order to access attributes in regards to an instance of `Node` you must as in most cases specify the receiver (`node` in this case) an call a method (`[]` with a given key argument). `node[key]` is identical to `node.attributes[key]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chef `node` is a way of referencing [attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html).

In essence, `node` can be used as a [Ruby Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html) which is publically available to your recipe code. Attributes can be set in the `.kitchen.yml`, or defaults can be set in the `attributes/default.rb` file of the cookbook. These attributes will be provided as hash mapped values in the `node` variable.

Comment: `node` is a [`Node`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Node). `Node::Attribute` as delegated by `Node#[]` is similar to a `Hash`  but `Node` is an `Object` and contextually very different from a `Hash`